# Get parameter name in spring boot convertor

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

With something like this:

```
record MyParam(...) {}

class MyParamConverter implements Converter<String, MyParam> {
  @Override
  public MyParam convert(String source) {
    ...
  }
}

record MyParams(MyParam myParam1, MyParam myParam2) {}

@RestController
class MyController {
    @GetMapping("/")
    public String index(@Valid MyParams myParams) {
      ...
    }
}
```

In the converter, I'd like to be able to determine which parameter is being converted, so that in case there are conversion issues I can throw an exception such as `myParam1 is invalid`. Is there a way to do this in spring (boot)?